# how to publish MVC 3 application to remote server from visual studio 2010

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010, iis-7

I have Server machine with installation of Windows 2008 R2, IIS 7, MVC 3, ASP.NET 4 Framework.
I want to publish ASP.NET MVC 3 Razor application using visual studio 2010 from local computer to remote server. The application has also used Entity Framework. What are required tool in my server to publish mvc 3 application and neccessary steps?

Answer (score 1):

use this URLs to do that

link to configure [Server side](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/09/13/automating-deployment-with-microsoft-web-deploy.aspx)   and this link to download [webDeploy](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy)

the link to do the publish in [Vs 2010](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/29/vs-2010-web-deployment.aspx)

and you have to install MVC tools in the server from this [link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4211)